# How to remove "{" in HashMap java

Tags: java, hashmap

when i am using HashMap the output is always like this {a,2}, instead of that i want an output like (a,2). 
How can i delete the curly bracket or modify it to ")" this.

```
wordCount.put("("+'"'+splitted[i].toLowerCase()+'"'+")",

wordCount.getOrDefault(splitted[i], 0) + 1);
```

*and the ouput is*

```
{("the")=1, ("be")=1, ("like")=1}
```

,but i want an output like this,

```
( “the” , 132 )
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than using the built-in `toString` method you should implement your own if you want a customised representation.

For example (using Java 8):

```
String toFormattedString(Map<String,Integer> map) {
    return map.entrySet().stream()
        .map(e -> String.format("(\"%s\", %d)", e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
        .collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
}
```

This way you can make the formatted output exactly as you want it to be, with the keys in the order you want etc.

Comment: Thanks this is more useful.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to replace the characters using `String#replace`?

```
String s = "(" + myHashMap.toString().replace("{", "").replace("}", "") + ")";
System.out.println(s); // (the=132)
```